# Can "how has " be abbreviated?

Tags: abbreviations

For example, if I say "How is your day going" I can abbreviate that to "How's" (How is).

But if I said "How has your day been" can I abbreviate *that* to "How's" (How has)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I often would say "How's your day been" or "How's your week been".

http://www.yourdictionary.com/how-s

**How's is defined as how is, how does or how has**

Comment: I assume you mean "week" :)

Comment: Yes, I meant "week".

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, and it's commonly used. It's much like how you might say *there's three books over there* when you mean *there **are** three books over there*.